# Google Maps: Need to add some private places(places only queryable by app)

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to add some private places(places only queryable by app) on the map with this API (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place)

The documentation says:

> When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby
>   Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a
>   moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added place
>   does not appear in Text Search or Radar Search results, or to other
>   applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.

But i'm trying to find a way to skip the moderation process. I don't want these places to be available to other applications or public as these are private to the business. I searched the docs but couldn't find it.

Is it possible to add business specific non-public places to google maps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to opt out of moderation when you submit a place via Place Add.

The feature request for this in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37972504

You can star the feature request to express your interest and subscribe to further notifications.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).